# How to replace specific parts of rows in dataframe for NA

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as folowing:

```
base<-matrix(1:20,nrow=10)
base1<-matrix(rnorm(180),nrow=10)
base2<-cbind(base,base1)
```

What i need is to change a part of each row for NAs, based on the first 2 columns (the numbers in each column show wich columns of that row need to be changed to NA. So the first row would be something like this:

```
base2[1,1:11]<-NA
base2[1,]
```

This works for 1 row, but my real dataframe has over 100.000 rows. Any idea on how to do this fast??

thanks!

Comment: This will be much more efficient if you keep it as a matrix instead of a data frame. You could do something like `apply(base2, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) {x[x[1]:x[2]] = NA; return(x)})`.

Comment: @Gregor is apply any faster than a loop?  Consider for example the following, which works for matrices and dataframes: `for (r in 1:nrow(base2)){ base2[r, base2[r,1]:base2[r,2]] <- NA }`

Comment: Apply won't be really any faster. In both cases, working on a matrix will be much faster than working on a data frame. Accessing and assigning elements is faster in a matrix than a data frame. Accessing and assigning elements is faster for matrix columns than matrix rows, so if OP really wants efficiency, keeping it as a matrix but transposing first would probably be even faster (and of course changing to `MARGIN = 2` in apply or making a corresponding change in the for loop).